# node.js could not use lib in /usr/local/lib

Tags: linux, node.js, png, shared-libraries

I'm using a node module **png** which use **libpng**. After installing **libpng**, I find some libs in **/usr/local/lib**. I require the **png** module:

```
var png = require('png')
```

It complained that **libpng16.so** could not be found.

> Error: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But **libpng16.so.16** does exist in **/usr/local/lib**. Then I copy all libpng* to **/usr/lib** and run code above again, no error for this time!

My question: how could I let Node search libs in **/usr/local/lib**?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try updating the cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743233/is-usr-local-lib-searched-for-shared-libraries

Answer (score 1):

This is a Linux "installing libraries" issue, not a node.js issue (I was confused by the same thing & landed here looking for ideas).

`make install` will typically copy the library to `/usr/local/lib` and output some boilerplate suggesting that you modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or update the `ld` config.  But it doesn't do this for you.
(One thing that can make this more confusing is that the compiler toolchain *will* search /usr/local by default, so any dependent libraries will compile/link fine.)

Running `ldconfig` (`/sbin/ldconfig`) as root or with sudo will update the run-time linker cache, and fix the problem.  If not, check that at least one of `/etc/ld.so.conf` or any of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` contains the line '/usr/local/lib'.

For more information, run `man ldconfig`