# How do I diagnose why a shared library is not found?

Tags: linux, ld, ldd

I am trying to run an app which is linked against `libboost_system.so`

```
$ ./app
app: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.63.0: cannot open shared object file: \
     No such file or directory
```

If I run `ldd` on the app, it shows it can't find the library:

```
$ ldd ./app
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdedb94000)
    libboost_system.so.1.63.0 => not found
    libpcap.so.1 => /lib64/libpcap.so.1 (0x00007f19a1a7b000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f19a1a70000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f19a1a69000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f19a1879000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f19a1733000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f19a1716000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f19a16f4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19a152a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f19a1ae5000)
```

The library is present on my system:

```
$ locate libboost_system.so.1.63.0
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.63.0

$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/libboost_system*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 47014 Jul  2 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    25 Jul  2 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.63.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 19816 Jul  2 16:57 /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.63.0
```

`ld` is configured with `/usr/local/lib`:

```
$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | sed 's/; /\n/g'
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")                    <----- here
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
```

I've also run `ldconfig` to refresh the cache, but that doesn't help.

I tried searching for `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` with `readelf`, neither are specified:

```
$ readelf -d ./app | grep -i path
< no results >
```

If I explicitly set `LD_LIBARY_PATH` then the library **is** found:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ldd ./app
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa9a5d000)
    libboost_system.so.1.63.0 => /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.63.0 (0x00007f5fff664000)
    libpcap.so.1 => /lib64/libpcap.so.1 (0x00007f5fff5fc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5fff5f1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5fff5ea000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5fff3fa000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5fff2b4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5fff297000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5fff275000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5fff0ab000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5fff66b000)
```

Why can't `ld` find `libboost_system.so.1.63.0` without specifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Not really an idea, but have you checked that you did not link with some '-L' options? May you have some version conflicts cause of other boost libs installed "somewhere" or is /usr/local/lib not searched as /usr/local/lib64 is in place? ld is static linker so please take a look in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ for the search path of ldd/dynamic loader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the "wrong" linker. [`ld`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) is the static linker and isn't what's used by at runtime to locate the shared libraries.

The dynamic linker, [ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), is what locates shared libraries.

The dynamic linker does look at the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and that's why it works if you set it.

If you want to update the search locations for dynamic linker (and not want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), you can create a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and update `/etc/ld.so.cache` with `ldconfig`.

Comment: Ah - TIL! Thank you!

Comment: Out of interest - do you know why `/usr/local/lib` is **not** configured as a search path by default?

Comment: ld.so looks at LD_LIBRARY_PATH, /etc/ld.so.conf, /lib and /usr/lib (in that order). Typically, system libs are installed at either /lib or /usr/lib but your boost libs are located at /usr/local/lib - it depends on how you installed boost (manual install?).

Comment: Yes I built from source and installed manually. The [FHS spec](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) suggests `/usr/local` is a standard directory, so I would have expected it to be included by default. Do you know if not doing so is a recent change adopted by some distros?

Comment: Seems red-hat related distros don't and debian based do (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/357867/28680) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743233/is-usr-local-lib-searched-for-shared-libraries/17653893#17653893))

Comment: Yes, `/usr/local` (or `/opt` in case of user apps) is the recommended location for libs maintained by admins. So that's the right approach.

Comment: As to why `/usr/local/lib` isn't in the default search paths, as you found, Debian-based systems (checked my mine) do include `/usr/local/lib` (in `libc.conf`). But I am more inclined to think that this isn't a good idea for the reasons mentioned by that [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/357867). So it's probably best to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH or rpath in your app, instead of updating system-wide ldconfig (this is my opinion of course).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The **diagnostic** is activated by `LD_DEBUG` (cf. [man ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#ENVIRONMENT)):

```
LD_DEBUG=libs ./a.out
```

It shows the search paths that the loader tried: (`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `R[UN]PATH` from the app or library's ELF, `ld.so.cache`).
Its output is a little long to copy here, but would look like this:

```
       265:     find library=libboost_system.so.1.63.0 [0]; searching
       265:      search path= [...]  (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
                   [trying many files...]
       265:      search path= [...]  (RUNPATH from file ./app)
                   [still trying many files...]
       265:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
                   [still trying many files...]
```

In your case, you'd probably have seen that `/usr/local/lib` was not in the cache. Depending on the distribution, it may look by default in `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or `/usr/local/lib64` or none at all.